# FAILED: loginTest java.lang.NullPointerException while using inheritance. How to fix it?

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception

How to resolve null pointer exception where running class using testng test. Trying to use three classes to make framework for automation.
I tried calling "driver.get(baseURL);" in setup of base class. it worked, but stuck at next method to enter user name. any help as stuck at one step?

```
//base class
package com.crmnext.testCases;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class BaseClass {

    public String baseURL = "https://my.crm.com/crmnext/login/login";
    public String username = "xyz@crmnext.com";
    public String password = "abc11";
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp ()
    {
        System.out.println("in setup");
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
    //  driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}

//test case class

package com.crmnext.testCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.crmnext.pageObjects.LoginPage;

public class TC1_LoginTest_001 extends BaseClass
{
    @Test
    public void loginTest()
    {
        driver.get(baseURL);
        LoginPage lp = new LoginPage(driver);

        lp.setUserName(username);
        
        lp.setPwd(password);
        
        lp.clickLogin();
                
    }

    
    
}

//Page class

package com.crmnext.pageObjects;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPage {
    
    WebDriver ldriver;
    
    public LoginPage(WebDriver rdriver)
    {
        System.out.println("In Login Page object class");
        ldriver = rdriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(ldriver, this);
    }
    
    @FindBy(css="#TxtName")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement txtUsername; 
    
    @FindBy (css = "[name='SecureTextBox.Text']")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement txtPassword;
    
    @FindBy (css ="body.bg-light-gray:nth-child(2) div.body-content.min-vh-100.login-background.h-100:nth-child(1) div.flexbox-row.w-100 div.login-box.relative div.login-container.flexbox-row.items-center.min-vh-100.h-100:nth-child(2) div.flex-1.login-box--inner div:nth-child(1) div.login-form form:nth-child(1) > input.login-button.button.w-100:nth-child(4)")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement btnLogin;
    
//Function to enter user name
    public void setUserName (String uname)
    {
        System.out.println("in set user name "+uname);
        ldriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        
        txtUsername.sendKeys(uname);
        System.out.println("After enter in user name");
    }
    
//Function to Enter password    
    public void setPwd (String pwd)
    {
        System.out.println("in set password");
        txtPassword.sendKeys(pwd);
    }
// Function to click button
    public void clickLogin ()
    {
        btnLogin.click();
    }
    

}
```

Getting null pointer exception. Tried similar queries posted. But, none helped.

```
FAILED: loginTest
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "com.crmnext.testCases.TC1_LoginTest_001.driver" is null
```

It seems driver is getting null.

Answer (score 1):

There is local `driver` variable in `setUp` method which is initialized but it is lost upon finishing the `setUp` method.  Thus, static field `driver` remains set to `null` and this causes NPE when the static field is referenced.

Fix `setUp` to remove declaration of local variable:

```java
public void setUp () {
    System.out.println("in setup");
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple (two) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instances initialized at different levels.

- One at the *class* (*`BaseClass`*) level as:

  ```
  public static WebDriver driver = null;
  ```
- Another at the *method* (*`setUp()`*) level as:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  ```

Once the program execution comes out of *`setUp()`* method, the `BaseClass` level WebDriver instance is accesed which is ***NULL***. hence you face [nullpointerexception](/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception)

---

### Solution

Declare the WebDriver instance at the *class* level as it is:

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

At the *`setUp()`* *method* level use the same WebDriver instance as:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```